# Select all checkboxes in grid view

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I Have the following grid view -

```
<asp:GridView ID="group_table" Runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" onprerender="group_table_PreRender" 
    onrowdatabound="group_table_RowDataBound"
    ClientIDMode="Static"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" Width="915px" BorderStyle=Ridge >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width=90>
       <HeaderTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="selectAllCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Select all"/>
       </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>

       <asp:CheckBox ID="selectCheckBox" runat="server"/>


     </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>
```

And have tried to implement the following javascript function so that when a user clicks `selectAllCheckBox` all checkboxes will be checked -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  var headerCheckbox = $('#group_table > tbody > tr > th > input:checkbox');

  headerCheckbox.click(function() {
     var headerChecked = $(this).attr('checked');
     var rowCheckboxes = $('#group_table > tbody > tr > td > input:checkbox');
     rowCheckboxes.attr('checked', headerChecked);
  }); 

});
```

But for some reason this is having no affect, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you give us the generated html output?

Comment: Shouldn't `headerCheckbox` selector be `$("#group_table > thead > tr > th > input:checkbox");`?

Comment: @mattytommo this is the correct answer and has fixed the problem, if you put the answer down I will mark it as correct as you were first to spot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment to the question (which you stated was correct), you have the selector for the `headerCheckbox` variable wrong. Table headings are in the `thead` **not** the `tbody`. Try this:

```
var headerCheckbox = $("#group_table > thead > tr > th > input:checkbox");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would have done it this way

```
<asp:GridView ID="group_table" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIDMode="Static"
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="915px" BorderStyle="Ridge">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="90">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="selectAllCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Select all" onclick="toggleChecks(this);" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="_CheckBox" runat="server" CssClass="psudoClass" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Add a `psudoClass` to the checkboxes to be checked, and do this

```
function toggleChecks(sender) {
   $(".psudoClass").each(function (index, item) {
        item.children[0].checked = sender.checked;
   });
}
```

Comment: Nice and tidy, I may try and implement this, good additional advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how asp:GridView generates the html, but maybe the problem is you add the click handler on   `tbody > tr > th`  instead of  `thead > tr > th` ?